# Why the dropdown list is not showing using android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView?

Tags: android, google-places-api, autocompletetextview

Could anyone tell me why the dropdown list is not showing using android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView? I followed the basic 5-step setup in the description.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The API android-PlacesAutocompleteTextView uses is the Google Places API Web Service instead of the Google Places API for Android. So simply enabling the Google Places API Web Service would work.